# Fetching multiple Images from a URL

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fetch, android-image

I have a one randomly selected link which have a multiple images so how can i fetch those images in my Android Studio I don't have any URL already, and display those images in RecyclerView.

Comment: share your code

Comment: single link can't have multiple images. I think your *link* has some data, which contains more links to multiple images, but it should be totally obvious that nobody except you knows the data format, and therefore can't help you. The only thing to say is: you need to parse that data.

Comment: yes, i have one web page which contain many images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this by one single url. You must have all the individual URLs for all the images, and then keep those URLs in a list/arraylist/array and then use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) / [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load those URLs into your `RecyclerView`'s `ImageView`.  you can see this [link](https://medium.com/@crossphd/android-image-loading-from-a-string-url-6c8290b82c5e).

Comment: can we use webScraping for image url?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your query.